# Still Microsoft Teams in Windows visual effects

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, microsoft-teams

I want to completely still Microsoft Teams visual effects outside of the app itself. How can I please do this?

With 'still' I mean that there shall be no visual effects whatever happens in my channels and meetings, except for inside the app itself, when it is not minimized.

The goal is to not have to be distracted by a visual change on my screen ever so often when something happens in a channel.

I don't even know all the terms to search for, but this far I have

- In Microsoft Teams app: Settings > Notifications > turned off everything except "show only in feed" and "email summary"
- In Windows: Searched every setting that has something to do with Notifications and Taskbar and turned off whatever I can find. Auto-hidden the taskbar.

I have gotten rid of the banner (that was fairly straight forward), but the Microsoft Teams icon in the taskbar refuses to still. Some settings changes results in a different behaviour (instead of a red symbol on the Microsoft Teams icon, it starts to flash orange, etc), but no setting makes it still.

The one idea I have left is to physically cover the icon with a piece of electrical tape.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what visual actions/elements/cues you want to prevent, because not all of them will be based on the application. Some are baked in to the OS (flashing taskbar icons, for instance). Please EDIT your question to more clearly list the visual elements you wish to prevent.

Comment: While I do understand your comment, that is where my problem lies. I simply don't know or can guess all different visual things that can be the effect of activity in Microsoft Teams. I realise that there may not even be another solution than to cover the icon physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close the window, there will no longer be an orange blinking icon, simply because there won't be an open Teams window. And even if you close the window, there is still another icon, in the system tray, that you can use to acces Teams. The orange blinking effect is a sign from Windows that the window needs attention, and, as far as I'm concerned, there doesn't exist an option to disable it. So the most simple way to solve this blinking problem is by closing the window.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Though I don't think it solves the case where I am in a Microsoft Teams meeting, but there is activity on other channels. I will check on a workday, and possibly mark this as the solution after that.

Comment: If you enable the option "try out the new Teams experience", then the meetings will be opened separately from the main window. In such a case, you can close the main Teams window, and the Teams icon won't be blinking anymore during a meeting because the other remaining windows aren't main windows.